# Error when using "ng generate" or "ng add"

Tags: angular, angular-cli

So i using angular version 8 in Termux Android ARM. This is the angular version information from Angular CLI:

```sh
$ ng version
    _                      _                 ____ _     ___
    / \   _ __   __ _ _   _| | __ _ _ __     / ___| |   |_ _|
   / △ \ | '_ \ / _` | | | | |/ _` | '__|   | |   | |    | |
  / ___ \| | | | (_| | |_| | | (_| | |      | |___| |___ | |
 /_/   \_\_| |_|\__, |\__,_|_|\__,_|_|       \____|_____|___|
                |___/


Angular CLI: 8.0.2
Node: 12.4.0
OS: android arm
Angular: <error>
... animations, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... language-service, platform-browser, platform-browser-dynamic
... router
```

But when i use `ng add` command to add PWA and service worker for my website project, it returned to error:

```sh
$ ng add @angular/pwa --project betaleapofazzamgithubio
Workspace needs to be loaded before it is used.
Error: Workspace needs to be loaded before it is used.
    at Workspace._assertLoaded (/data/data/com.termux/files/home/node_modules/@angular-devkit/core/src/experimental/workspace/workspace.js:108:19)
    at Workspace.getProjectByPath (/data/data/com.termux/files/home/node_modules/@angular-devkit/core/src/experimental/workspace/workspace.js:156:14)
    at getProjectByCwd (/data/data/com.termux/files/home/node_modules/@angular/cli/utilities/config.js:103:26)
    at Object.getConfiguredPackageManager (/data/data/com.termux/files/home/node_modules/@angular/cli/utilities/config.js:116:25)
    at Object.getPackageManager (/data/data/com.termux/files/home/node_modules/@angular/cli/utilities/package-manager.js:32:35)
    at new AddCommand (/data/data/com.termux/files/home/node_modules/@angular/cli/commands/add-impl.js:25:49)
    at Object.runCommand (/data/data/com.termux/files/home/node_modules/@angular/cli/models/command-runner.js:172:25)
    at async default_1 (/data/data/com.termux/files/home/node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/cli/index.js:32:31)
```

Because the error, i using `ng generate` command instead of `ng add` command. But it's returned to error too. This is the error:

```sh
$ ng generate service-worker
Workspace needs to be loaded before it is used.
Error: Workspace needs to be loaded before it is used.
    at Workspace._assertLoaded (/data/data/com.termux/files/home/node_modules/@angular-devkit/core/src/experimental/workspace/workspace.js:108:19)
    at Workspace.getProjectByPath (/data/data/com.termux/files/home/node_modules/@angular-devkit/core/src/experimental/workspace/workspace.js:156:14)
    at Object.getProjectByCwd (/data/data/com.termux/files/home/node_modules/@angular/cli/utilities/config.js:103:26)
    at GenerateCommand.getDefaultSchematicCollection (/data/data/com.termux/files/home/node_modules/@angular/cli/models/schematic-command.js:251:38)
    at GenerateCommand.parseSchematicInfo (/data/data/com.termux/files/home/node_modules/@angular/cli/commands/generate-impl.js:70:35)
    at GenerateCommand.initialize (/data/data/com.termux/files/home/node_modules/@angular/cli/commands/generate-impl.js:16:54)
    at GenerateCommand.validateAndRun (/data/data/com.termux/files/home/node_modules/@angular/cli/models/command.js:127:20)
    at async Object.runCommand (/data/data/com.termux/files/home/node_modules/@angular/cli/models/command-runner.js:178:24)
    at async default_1 (/data/data/com.termux/files/home/node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/cli/index.js:32:31)
```

Please the help for this error and fix this error solution.

Comment: Can you take a picture how your project look like ? Do you have angular.json file ?

Comment: run command npm install first. Once it is done then start adding a component/service.

Comment: @TonyNgo i have angular.json file in my angular website project

Answer (score 1):

1. Switch to your project folder or work-space after creating the project.
2. Run `npm install`
3. Run following commands `ng generate component <componentName> //*for adding new component*` or `ng generate service <serviceName> //*for adding new service*`